# Validar datos que ingresa el usuario en un array de inputs dinamicos - React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

Estoy creando un array de inputs que el usuario puede crear dinámicamente según su preferencia, este array lo guardaré en un estado y quisiera validar que ningún input esté vacío o nulo al momento en que el usuario presiona en "addRecipe", ya se está validando si el array de datos está vacío para que el usuario agregue al menos un elemento, pero el problema está al momento de valira si el usuario dejo en blanco el input.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TextInput } from 'react-native'
import { Button } from 'react-native-elements'
import { size } from 'lodash'

export default function AddRecipeForm (props) {
 const [ingredients, setIngredients] = useState([])

 const addRecipe = () => {

    if (!ingredients) {
      console.log('No puedes dejar campos en blanco!')
    } else if (size(ingredients) === 0) {
      console.log('Debes agregar al menos un ingrediente')
    } else {
      console.log('ok')
    }

  }
 const handleChange = (i, event) => {
    const values = [...ingredients]
    values[i].ingredient = event
    setIngredients(values)
  }

  const handleAdd = () => {
    const values = [...ingredients]
    values.push({ ingredients: null })
    setIngredients(values)
  }
  const handleRemove = (i) => {
    const values = [...ingredients]
    values.splice(i, 1)
    setIngredients(values)
  }
 return(
   <View>
        <Text>Ingredientes</Text>
        {ingredients.map((ingredient, idx) => {
          return (
            <View key={`${ingredient}-${idx}`}>

              <TextInput
                placeholder='Ingrediente'
                value={ingredient.value}
                onChange={e => handleChange(idx, e.nativeEvent.text)}
              />
              <Button title='x' onPress={() => handleRemove(idx)} />

            </View>
          )
        })}
         <Button title='+' onPress={() => handleAdd()} />
         <Button
        title='Crear'
        onPress={addRecipe}
      />
      </View>
)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacer uso de la función [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/every) del *Array prototype*.

La función `every` espera una *callback* como argumento. Esta *callback* debe devolver un *boolean*. Si todos los elementos del *array* cumplen dicha condición, la función `every` devolverá `true`; por lo contrario, si hay algún elemento que no cumpla la condición, se devolverá `false`.

```
const checkIngredients = ingredients => {
    const isIngredientValid = ingredient => {
        // Aquí pones tu lógica para determinar si un
        // ingrediente es válido, devolviendo
        // true o false
        return true;
    }

    if (!ingredients) {
        console.log('No puedes dejar campos en blanco!');
    }
    else if (ingredients.length === 0) {
        console.log('Debes agregar al menos un ingrediente')
    }
    else if (!ingredients.every(isIngredientValid)) {
        // Aquí qué hacer cuando hay algún ingrediente inválido
    } else {
        console.log('ok')
    }
}
```

Alternativamente, puedes hacer uso, también, de la función [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/some).

Análoga a `every`, la función `some` también recibe una *callback* como argumento. Dicha *callback* deberá devolver un *boolean*. Si **al menos un elemento** del *array* cumple esa condición, el resultado de `some` será `true`; `false` en caso contrario.

```
const checkIngredients = ingredients => {
    const isIngredientInvalid = ingredient => {
        // Aquí pones tu lógica para determinar si un
        // ingrediente es inválido, devolviendo
        // true (inválido) o false (válido)
        return true;
    }

    if (!ingredients) {
        console.log('No puedes dejar campos en blanco!');
    }
    else if (ingredients.length === 0) {
        console.log('Debes agregar al menos un ingrediente')
    }
    // En este caso, no hay que negar el resultado
    else if (ingredients.some(isIngredientInvalid)) {
        // Aquí qué hacer cuando hay algún ingrediente inválido
    } else {
        console.log('ok')
    }
}
```

Espero que sirva.

Comment: Está genial! Solo me queda una duda, tengo un problema para acceder al estado y ver que lo que agregó el usuario en el JSON del state, no tenga campos vacíos, como lo puedo lograr en el "isIngredientInvalid" que me muestras?

Comment: No lo he puesto porque no sé qué campos tiene cada `ingredient`. Viendo el código me figuro que tiene un solo campo `value`. El caso más sencillo sería ver que `value` es un valor *falsy* o vacío: `return !ingredient.value || ingredient.value === '';`.

Comment: Pero la razón por la que he separado esta validación en una función es porque puede ser más compleja que esto (y yo realmente no sé en qué casos para ti el `input` es válido o no). Teniendo esa comprobación aislada permite modificarla a futuro cuando estas *specs* cambien.

Comment: Justo era la validación que necesitaba amigo! Por ahora solo quería saber si los campos eran null o no para mostrar el mensaje, me ayudaste mucho, gracias!